# Make internal classes visible to other assemblies

Tags: c#, linqpad, internals

Is it possible to make internal classes from my assembly visible to other assemblies?

I know about the AssemblyInfo file and the `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo()]` attribute, but it doesn't work in my case.

The main purpose is to make it possible to call methods from LINQPAD, so this `[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("LINQPad")]` doesn't work. I don't know why. In my project, I'm using dependency resolver, and it is hard to do such a thing in LINQPAD. Any suggestions?

Comment: I strongly suspect that LINQPad is generating assemblies dynamically - it's probably not the LINQPad assembly itself that needs access to your types.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Autocomplete doesnt work too. I guess it LINQPAD assembly.

Comment: Autocomplete is almost certainly based on reflection - I would fully expect it to be filtering to public properties only. After all, the LINQPad assembly itself doesn't contain *direct* calls to your code, does it?

Comment: @Jon Skeet you are right...ok what is the solution?

Comment: Why not just make the classes public? What is the use case for letting a user write code in LINQPad but not directly compile against your assemblies?

Comment: @mike z because of these classes from a big project where internal modifier required.

Comment: Sounds like you should be contacting Joe Albahari with a feature request...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I've just uploaded [a new beta](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx) that allows this to work.

Add the following attribute to the libraries whose internals you want LINQPad to access:

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("LINQPadQuery")]
```

You'll also need to enable this feature in LINQPad's preferences (Edit | Preferences | Advanced).

Let me know how you get along.

Comment: Works for me. There have been times when I have had to revert to reflection to access internal methods, so this is will be a handy feature, so Thank you.

Comment: The warning about the access level is gone for me too, but now I get this: `Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'Database.Model.CustomDataContext' is less accessible than class 'UserQuery'`. Do you know how i can get around this?
The signature of CustomDataContext is `internal partial class CustomDataContext : DbContext`

Comment: I tried the version v4.46.11 and it works!! thank you so much :)

Comment: I was searching for visual studio - nevertheless this answer worked for me.

Comment: What about the signed assemblies? Is there any possibility?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. LINQPad 7 and .NET 6, EF Core 7. Also tried newer csproj InternalsVisibleTo with both LINQPadQuery and LINQPad. Any idea? Assembly is not signed. VS v17.9.1

Answer (score 8):

You can also go to the project properties into AssemblyInfo.cs file and set it there.

For example:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("*****)]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("*****")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("*****")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("[HERE IS YOUR ASSEMBLY WHERE YOU WANT TO SEE INTERNALS OF CURRENT ASSEMBLY")]

// Setting ComVisible to false makes the types in this assembly not visible 
// to COM components.  If you need to access a type in this assembly from 
// COM, set the ComVisible attribute to true on that type.
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]

// The following GUID is for the ID of the typelib if this project is exposed to COM
[assembly: Guid("6fbd2c14-031d-48cc-9cc6-f1b85d701e89")]

// Version information for an assembly consists of the following four values:
//
//      Major Version
//      Minor Version 
//      Build Number
//      Revision
//
// You can specify all the values or you can default the Build and Revision Numbers 
// by using the '*' as shown below:
// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: I find this is more helpful than the accepted answer because it says where to put this information: AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 3):

In .NET 5+, according to [manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#internalsvisibleto), add the following group to your `csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <InternalsVisibleTo Include="LINQPad" />
</ItemGroup>
```