# Public Access Modifier Across Assemblies

Tags: .net-core, .net-8.0

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 8 project.

I have a solution setup like the following:

- ProjectA

  - ClassA
- LibraryB

  - Has a Project reference to Project A
  - Class B
- LibraryC

  - Has a Project reference to Project B
  - ClassC

```cs
public class ClassA
{
    public void Foo();
}

internal class ClassB : IClassB
{
    private ClassA a;

    public ClassB(ClassA a) 
    {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public void Bar() 
    {
        a.Foo();
    }
}

//Project C gets IClassB via DI
public interface IClassB
{
  void Bar();
}

public class ClassC
{
    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        // It is possible create a ClassA in here, which surprises me!
    }
}
```

I am surprised that the Project Reference in Project B makes the public classes in ProjectA available in Project C.

Does a project reference give you access to the referenced project's public members and the public members of all the projects that the referenced project references?

Sorry for the yucky verbiage on the question, but I can't come up with a better way to ask it!

Comment: _"Does a project reference give you access to the referenced project's public members and the public members of all the projects that the referenced project references?"_ - Yes, and the term is _transitive dependency_. But it's not-a-good-thing when a dependent project has an implicit transitive dependency because it makes it harder to predict (and prevent) upstream breaking changes.

Comment: Suppose there's a public FunctionB (in Project B), which returns ClassA or expects ClassA as input. In Project C, because the Project B's reference, you can call FunctionB, but...how to deal with ClassA as input/output if that type wouldn't be resolved implicitly?

Comment: That's the usual behaviour of public accessors. If you own the libraries you may opt for an internal accessor + internalsvisibleto. It smells like a bad design choise but it works.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354157/make-internal-classes-visible-to-other-assemblies

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Dai for the term I was looking for: **transitive dependency**

Based on that I was able to track down the **DisableTransitiveProjectReferences** project file setting, which allows you to resolve the situation listed above.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#disabletransitiveprojectreferences

In my example above, the *DisableTransitiveProjectReferences* setting needs to be in the .csproj file for LibraryC, not LibraryB.  I put it in LibraryB at first and discovered that was incorrect.